# How to replace/populate a bash case statement automatic

Tags: bash, select, case

How to improve the following batch script by making so whenever a new script is added into the directory, it doesn't require to manually hardcode an extra line of code in script.
like: `3) source $(pwd)/script-3.sh; myfunc;;`

script:

```
#Menu script
title="Menu"
prompt="Pick an option(number): "

#options=(         
#        "script-1.sh" \
#        "script-2.sh" \
#        "script-3.sh" \
#         )

path=$(pwd) 
array=($path/*.sh)
options=( "${array[@]##*/}" )


echo "$title"
PS3="$prompt"
select opt in "${options[@]}" "Quit"; do 
    case "$REPLY" in
    1) source $(pwd)/script-1.sh; myfunc;;
    2) source $(pwd)/script-2.sh; myfunc;;
    3) source $(pwd)/script-3.sh; myfunc;;

    $((${#options[@]}+1))) echo "Goodbye!"; break;;
    *) echo "Invalid option. Try another one.";continue;;
    esac
done
```

##### How to automate this part ?

```
select opt in "${options[@]}" "Quit"; do 
    case "$REPLY" in
    1) source $(pwd)/script-1.sh; myfunc;;
    2) source $(pwd)/script-2.sh; myfunc;;
    3) source $(pwd)/script-3.sh; myfunc;;

    $((${#options[@]}+1))) echo "Goodbye!"; break;;
    *) echo "Invalid option. Try another one.";continue;;
    esac
done
```

this is the current manual part, where need to be hard-coded a value everytime a new script is added.

for example, lets say I added a new script called" `script-99.sh`

then it would need to hardcode it in the main script like this:

```
    case "$REPLY" in
    1) source $(pwd)/script-1.sh; myfunc;;
    2) source $(pwd)/script-2.sh; myfunc;;
    3) source $(pwd)/script-3.sh; myfunc;;
    4) source $(pwd)/script-99.sh; myfunc;;  ##Had to hardcode this line
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be

```
select opt in "${options[@]}" "Quit"; do
  script=script-$REPLY.sh
  if [[ -f $script ]]
  then
    source $script
  else
    echo Goodbye
    break
  fi
done
```

This also catches the case that someone deletes a script while the *select*-loop is still in process.

A more stable solution would be

```
quitstring=Quit
select opt in "${options[@]}" $quitstring; do
  [[ $opt == $quitstring ]] && break
  source $opt
done
```

Answer (score 0):

After lots attempts, come up with this:

```
select opt in "${options[@]}" "Quit"; do 
    source $(pwd)/$opt; myfunc
done
```

it is working!

however to exit the script it need to press Ctrl+z
this part of the code bellow which used to exit the script, I wasn't able to figure out how to adapt into the solution above.

```
    $((${#options[@]}+1))) echo "Goodbye!"; break;;
    *) echo "Invalid option. Try another one.";continue;;
```

so this is not a complete answer.

Comment: If the user selects the "Quit" option, `$opt` will be set to "Quit", so you need to check for that value. Also, the standard way to exit a `select` loop is with Control-D (end-of-file), not Control-Z (which pauses the current command/script/whatever, and puts it in the background).